# What is the python regular expression equivalent of grep -i -A 2 'StatusExit: Succeeded'?

Tags: python, regex, expression, python-re

I'm trying to use python regular expressions instead of the linux grep. I usually have a log file like this

```
StatusExit: Fail - User did not exit properly
StatusExit: Succeeded - User did a good job
The user was able to exit on time
The user is happpy
StatusExit: Fail - User did not exit properly
StatusExit: Pending - User is stuck but good to go nonetheless
```

I want to find the matching line and also the trailing 2 lines after the matching line. I also want to find all instances of where this happens. I am having a hard time understanding how python regex expressions work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably this , but not sure `(?si)(StatusExit: Succeeded(.*?(\n)){1,3})`

Comment: `python regex` should work the same way as `regex` in other programs - (of course sometimes programs may have small differences). In `grep` you can also use `regex` but using options can be simpler. You could also use options in Python and create code which display 2 lines after match without using regex.